# Is there a way to use flatc generated classes within a Java 8 runtime?

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror, flatbuffers

I have working code that runs fine in OpenJDK Java 9, but throws the NoSuchMethodError below when run in OPenJDK Java 8. Even when flatc is built on a system with Java 8 I still get this error. Is there any way to generate classes that will work in Java 8?

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.position(I)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
at com.google.flatbuffers.FlatBufferBuilder.createString(FlatBufferBuilder.java:605)
at jeromq_and_flatbuffers.io.MonsterIO.writeTo(MonsterIO.java:54)
at jeromq_and_flatbuffers.io.MonsterIO.writeTo(MonsterIO.java:1)
at jeromq_and_flatbuffers.core.MonsterPublisher.sendMessage(MonsterPublisher.java:80)
at jeromq_and_flatbuffers.core.MonsterPublisher.run(MonsterPublisher.java:104)
at jeromq_and_flatbuffers.core.Main.lambda$0(Main.java:46)
at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
at jeromq_and_flatbuffers.core.Main.main(Main.java:46)
```

I realize there were a number of NIO improvements in Java 9, but my network IT has constrained us to Java 8.

Comment: If the Java runtime does not have a feature, then you can't use it!

Comment: Yep looks like you're using a ByteBuffer method which is not present in JDK 8 or below. Just rewrite your code to use something else. Or, at least, FlatBufferBuilder is using the problematic method... maybe there's a java 8-compatible version of the library?

Comment: I don't get that. That method has been there from the start of [nio](https://web.mit.edu/java_v1.5.0_22/distrib/share/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#position(int))

Comment: Ok, thank you. Supposedly FlatBufferBuilder's cast to Buffer is supposed to get around the issue, and javap shows the method. I

Comment: Method has been there since start of NIO, but in Java 9 I think they changed it.

Comment: Are you using the latest Flabuffers package? I've added workarounds to avoid exactly this error.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to either not use downloaded Flatbuffers 2.0.0 dependency from Maven central repo, which is built with Java 9 or higher. Instead, build Flatbuffers jar from source by downloading Flatbuffers source, then executing maven package in the top level directory, within a Java 8 environment. Then take the jar in target and use that in your app. This got me past the error.

A better solution is to use Flatbuffers 2.0.2 or later, which fixes the problem.

Comment: the 2.0.2 package has fixes in it that are supposed to make it compatible with Java 8, see https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/pull/6671, so it is not clear why this does not work?